# CakePHP cake back console -app not doing what I expect

Tags: cakephp

So so so sorry if this is mentioned somewhere but I've tried searching high and low and can't find it anywhere. :(

Firstly, I'm a right newbie to cake. I purchased a book, beginning cakephp, apress, David Golding, which in here it makes use of the cake bake (really wish it didnt as it really isnt making sense!). I couldn't get this set up with cygwin but have it installed with the windows console.

In the book it tells me to enter:
cake bake -app ~/Sites/blog/app
and next the screen which it shows is the what would like to bake. Views, controllers etc etc.

However I have no idea what the Sites is as its the first time its mentioned this!!
So i'm trying:

cake bake -app ~C:/wamp/www/blog/app 
and I'm getting the next screen as:
what is the path to the project you would like to bake?

Please please please help, where am I going wrong why aren't I seeing the what would like to bake. Views, controllers etc etc screen?? I'm really stuck now on this as the next chapter needs the bits the console creates.

I'm using wamp and the latest cakephp. 
my cake folder is ~C:/wamp/www/blog/ (blog is the cake renamed).

my console environment setting is set up as: ;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10;C:\wamp\www\blog\app\Console

I really appreciate anyones/everyones help. I'm probably being a right spanner but can't get my head round understanding what I should enter.

Many Thanks in advance, 
Alan

Answer (score 0):

you should always navigate to your app dir and execute cake from there (relatively):

```
 /path/to/test/>../lib/Cake/Console/cake
```

or - if you have a Config folder - probably also with (although I never used that one before)

```
 /path/to/test/>Console/cake
```

that's how it works in 2.x. foolproof.

@see http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2761

also see http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/31/freshly-baked-cake2-0-tips/